# Woocommerce 5.4.1: How to Add Hook to a specific Post on Archive Page - Shop Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

After a lot of search and nothing found, how can I apply this Hook just for a Single Post on the Archive Page?

The goal is to use different Text for different Post, but in this position of the post. **Ex. 10%, 20%, 30%**

As you see on the picture, the function is applied for every Post and this is not the goal.

Maybe I must use the Post ID to select and use the function for the specific Post.

```
// define the woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title callback 
function action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title(  ) { 
        echo "<div>
        <small>Get a discount of 10% on any item</small>
      </div>";
}; 
   // add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 10, 0 );
```

**Result of the script above:**

[image]

Comment: You can apply different texts per product based on the product ID. Based on 1 or more product categories. A specific product tag, etc... a product ID is unique, while tags or categories can be applied for multiple products. In other words, plenty of choice and it depends on your wishes

Comment: _"After a lot of search and nothing found.."_ -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+%22specific+products%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use product ID to add text to specific post

```
// define the woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title callback 
function action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title(  ) { 
global $post;
if($post->ID == your_post_id){
        echo "<div>
        <small>Get a discount of 10% on any item</small>
      </div>";}
}; 
   // add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gentlemen! The Light is on!!